# How to set ID to use objectify cache efficiently?

Tags: google-app-engine, caching, objectify

In the google documentations it says that queries are not cached in Objectify. Only way to call from cache is to get by id. Where I am confused is how can I know Ids to get it by Id when the Ids are generated randomly. Let's say some user had made a search on the fast food restaurants in New York and the query is called for the first time. My understanding is if another user makes the same search Objectify will not get the results from cache. So I should somehow know IDs to get from the cache when another user searches for the samething.

For example: ID = restaurant+newyork+fastfood+integer

If I create an ID with a logic like this then I can try loading with that Id, if not found, do the query. Is this what should I do? What is the common practice to use the cache with Objectify?

Answer (score 0):

Documentation on Objectify caching is [here](https://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Caching).

Basically, put @Cache on entities you want served out of the cache, and objectify will handle the rest transparently when you interact with it's load() apis. Whether or not you get cache hits or misses will depend on usage pattern (reads vs writes, cache flushes etc).

If you want to only cache particular calls and not others, you'll need to manage it yourself.